# Type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

this is my code in objective c

```
 id locationValue = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey];
if (locationValue)
{
    UIApplication *app  = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    }];
    [self startLocationUpdates];
}
```

i define locationValue as AnyObjectType and the error mentioned as the title hits at the line

```
if(locationValue)
```

I am converting this to swift .. so please help..

Comment: i m using xcode 7.2 , swift 2.0

Comment: i am stuck with how to define that if condition with that locationValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of any condition in an if statement must have a type that conforms to the BooleanType protocol, which means that the condition must be a boolean expression.

`locationValue` is not a boolean expression, you want `if(locationValue != nil)`.

Comment: again an error that "type AnyObject can never be nil , comparison isn't allowed"

Comment: Declare it as `AnyObject?`